# How to destroy a modeless dialog when it loses the focus?

Tags: mfc, dialog, modeless

I have a created modeless dialog and placed a grid on top of this dialog(Grid completely overlaps on dialog).This will be shown when user clicks F2.Now when user clicks left mouse button outside the dialog i want to destroy this dialog.
Can please somebody suggest how can i destroy the dialog?? (Just like Tool tip gets destroyed when clicked outside)

Comment: Or are you wondering how to detect when you lose focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store a pointer to the dialog in your main window. When you want to destroy it, call `CDialog::DestroyWindow()` on it.